# Merging adapters in android

Tags: android

I am having two different data in two different adapters.
Now i want to merge both data in a single adapter.
is this possible??
How can I do that?

Regards,

vani

Comment: Take a look on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9734437/608238

Answer (score 5):

Maybe CommonsGuy's MergeAdapter source will help, read about documentation here http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Answer (score 4):

It's 2020 now, [MergeAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter) is introduced to recyclerview 1.2.0-alpha02

Comment: It has been renamed to ConcatAdapter in [version 1.2.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview#recyclerview-1.2.0-alpha04)