# Display two lists (same listactivity)

Tags: android, sdk, listactivity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging adapters in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403290/merging-adapters-in-android)

I have two lists of elements from a database:

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter list1 =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.normal, c, from, to);

    SimpleCursorAdapter list2 =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bold, d, from, to);
```

How do I display them at the same time (one after another or with the elements mixed up, I don't care)? Currently I'm using setListAdapter(list); to display one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need the CWAC [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked great.