# Setting more than one adapter for a single list view

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

Is it possible for setting more than one adapter to a single list?

For example

- `list.setAdapter(adapter1);`
- `list.setAdapter(adapter2);`

Comment: may I know the reason why you need something like this?

Comment: if you use more then one adapter then last adapter is set to listview...any special reason for more than one adapter for listview ?

Comment: why you want this functionality? Anything special

Comment: Agree with the other commenters: unless you tell us what behavior you are seeking, we cannot readily help you.

Comment: I am trying to develop a world clock.i have to show name of the place and its time in analog clock as one entry to the list.i have to draw analog clock on the list

Comment: Please modify your question. Specify your requirements and problem/error you are getting.

Comment: I think the Q is strait-forward..? Simple and to the point... `Is it possible for setting more than one adapter to a single list?`

Comment: Ok who cares why he is asking the question? why do you care can you tell us that please? Either help or get out of the way please

Comment: Ok so it looks like the answer might be to use a ListFragment in your Activity. This is the kind of help we are looking for when we ask questions. We don't need people judging what are motives are that is not part of the question or this site. Either please help or get lost...I think that is quite fair, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try attaching multiple adapters to a single adapter like here

[android attaching multiple adapters to one adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964259/android-attaching-multiple-adapters-to-one-adapter)

Or maybe this 
http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

if I understand what you need it for correctly

Pls update why you want it for so we have a better understanding

Comment: the second link was dead