# Multiple Adapters for a Card Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How do you add multiple adapters to a listview? After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118809/setting-more-than-one-adapter-for-a-single-list-view) question and following the tutorial, I still don't have what I want.

## Scenario

Adding two types of text into an SQLite database table and retrieving them on another activity in the form of a card with a title on top, a separator, and the content underneath.

### Visuals

Adding content to main list:
[image: Adding title and content]

Card on main list:
[image: Main Card view]

## My Code

I take it no one really needs to see the layout for the edittext part so I'll jump right to the main card row item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_selecter_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is where I add the edittext strings to the database:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lists (Title VARCHAR, Content VARCHAR);");

addListBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean  cancel = false;
        String listName = listNameET.getText().toString();
        String content = contentET.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(listName)) {
            listNameET.setError("Please enter a list name.");
            cancel = true;
        } else if (listName.contains("'") || listName.contains("\"")) {
            listNameET.setError("Please enter alphanumeric (abc123) characters only.");
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(content)) {
            contentET.setError("Field cannot be left blank.");
            cancel = true;
        } else if (content.contains("'") || content.contains("\"")) {
            contentET.setError("Please enter alphanumeric (abc123) characters only.");
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            //Nothing happens
        } else {
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Lists VALUES('" + listName + "', '" + content + "');");
            db.close();
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is where it is retrieved in the listview activity:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Title from Lists", null);
Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT Content from Lists", null);

final ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>();

if (c.moveToFirst() && c2.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        titleList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title")));
        contentList.add(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Content")));
    } while (c.moveToNext() && c2.moveToNext());
}

ArrayAdapter<String> titleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listname_row, R.id.tvTitle, titleList);
ArrayAdapter<String> contentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listname_row, R.id.tvContent, contentList);

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfNames);
//Since Java works top to bottom, the contentAdapter is set even though
//this line is here.
lv.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
lv.setAdapter(contentAdapter);
db.close();
c.close();
```

I need to be able to attach the title and the content to the same listview.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom Adapter like this:

```
class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    List<String> mTitles;
    List<String> mContents;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v;

        //inflate view if needed
        ...

        TextView tv_title;
        TextView tv_content;

        String title = mTitles.get(position);
        String content = mContents.get(position);

        tv_title.setText(title);
        tv_content.setText(content);


        return v;
    }

}
```

Now past 2 list of String to this Adapter and call setAdapter of ListView.