# Android With Listview and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any mistake in code because I am getting the only price in the listview and not the name can anyone help me out? I've tried so many methods to solve it but in last it let me post on StackOverflow to ask you people for the help, I am really stuck in it. I'll be really thankful to you for this help. Model class will also be provided if needed.

```
 private ListView mlistView;
private ArrayList<String>list;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

private ArrayList<String>Pricelist;
private ArrayAdapter<String> Priceadapter;
private DatabaseReference ref;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private FoodItemclass fooditem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rice_after_login);
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("Rice");


    fooditem = new FoodItemclass();
    mlistView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("Rice");
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    Pricelist = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.ItemNameIds,list);
    Priceadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.ItemPriceId,Pricelist);
   ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

               fooditem = dataSnapshot.getValue(FoodItemclass.class);
               list.add(fooditem.getName());
               Pricelist.add(String.valueOf(fooditem.getPrice()));
               mlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
               mlistView.setAdapter(Priceadapter);
       }

       @Override
       public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118809/setting-more-than-one-adapter-for-a-single-list-view

Comment: Please share your adapter. As I can see you are sending the Price List only to your adapter. You need to send the names as well. You might consider making an object having them both. So that you can have the list of objects which will be passed to the adapter.

Comment: I've not made an adapter class , i've made model class and then getting values from firebase database into listview textviews but the issue is that i am getting only price and not then name :(

Comment: Please add the content of your adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

you can only set one adapter to your list view so thats why you get the recent assign adapter result

```
@Override
   public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

           fooditem = dataSnapshot.getValue(FoodItemclass.class);
           list.add(fooditem.getName()+ " "+String.valueOf(fooditem.getPrice());
           mlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

**NOTE:** the space between both name and price value is a separator

**Recommend** This is a bad approach to do so. you should use RecyclerView to show multiple values

Comment: I tried this code too but it shows data only on  one textview not multiple textviews :(

Comment: then you should use your own custom AdapterClass to do so

Comment: Any reference link ?

Comment: I did all the same code as per your reference but the app is opening and not showing anything ? can you please tell me why ?

Comment: you mean you used the recycler view approach too but it not showing any thing ?

Comment: yeh brother its not showing anything i first created the sample project of the the reference you provide

Comment: can i review your code i think you are missing something

Answer (score 0):

The answer from faiizii has the gist of the problem: you can only have one adapter on a list view, so you should only call `setAdapter` once. Since `onChildAdded` will be called for each child, you shouldn't call `setAdapter` in there (nor in any of the other `onChild...` methods).

The solution is to move the calls to `setAdapter` out of the listener:

```
list = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.ItemNameIds,list);
mlistView.setAdapter(adapter);

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
       fooditem = dataSnapshot.getValue(FoodItemclass.class);
       list.add(fooditem.getName()+": "+fooditem.getPrice());
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   ...

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
       throw databaseError.toException();
   }
});
```

As you'll see we now call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) inside `onChildAdded`. This lets the adapter know that its data has changed, which in turn then means that it refreshes the list view.

Comment: No brother it does not work :( I still get the same result

Comment: Why do you have two adapters? Each view should be associated with a single adapter. If you need to show two values in the view, you should create a single `List` with those two values for each item, create an `ArrayAdapter` on that single `List`, and then associate the single adapter with the view.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the two values in a single string. But the better approach is what I have in my previous comment.

Comment: I did the same but when i have to pass the data from the list view to another activity it sends the whole string and i want the price and the name to be on diff textview so calculation for further process will be easy and im stuck in it.

Comment: Did you already investigate how to get two subviews in each list item? You posted a quite broad use-case, and this was definitely the first problem in there. "How to show two subviews in each item of a list view" sounds like a topic that has probably been covered before.

Comment: Yes i've investigate but didn't find any proper use-case