# Show List File in listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to show files in list view  :

It works perfectly. Now I'm trying to add TextView to this Listview so I tried 
this i:
I don't want to use adapter class.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    file = new File(path);
    setListView();
}

public void setListView(){

    String[] mFilesList = file.list();


    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    mArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    fArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i<mFilesList.length; i++){
        mArray.add(mFilesList[i]);


    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mFilesList.length; i++) {
        fArray.add(mFilesList[i].length()+" files");

    }



    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext()
            , R.layout.rows, R.id.textView1,mArray);

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapterSecond = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext()
            , R.layout.rows, R.id.textView2,fArray);`



    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapterSecond);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

It's showing just one textview. Why?

Comment: will u explain what u want to do

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964259/android-attaching-multiple-adapters-to-one-adapter

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` accepts only one `Adapter`. Your last code line changes the `ListView` adapter from `mAdapterSecond` to `mAdapter`. What you need in your case is to implement your custom adapter that fill the two `TextView` as you wish.

Comment: all i need is to add atextview to the listview