# How to separate ImageView from adapter of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview with and adapter that changes the title (TextView) and an image (ImageView) of all single item. But I have a problem, I also have and inputsearch (edittext) with the function TextChangedListener to search any single item of the list view. But actualy this is mi code of the TextChangedListener:

```
 /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            Alimentacion.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

This generales a null pointer in this line: **Alimentacion.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);** I think that the null pointer is because when I'm going to search something I only want to  search by the title but in the adapter I have the title and the **image** so tries to search the title and the image and returs the null pointer, I think.
How can separate these thing to search only for the title?
My full code:
** OncreateView of myfragment.xml** (the list view is in a fragment)

```
// List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

 // Set the Text to try this out
        lv = (ListView)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

// Listview Data
        final String categorias[] = {"1. Huevos y Lacteos", "2. Carnes y Derivados", "3. Pescados y Mariscos", "4. Aceites y grasos", "5. Verduras y hortalizas",
                "6. Frutas", "7. Bebidas",
                "8. Comida Rapida", "9. Pasta y Cereales", "10. Bolleria y Snacks"};
        Integer ImgCategorias[] = {R.drawable.cat1,R.drawable.cat2,R.drawable.cat3,R.drawable.cat4,R.drawable.cat5,R.drawable.cat6
                ,R.drawable.cat7,R.drawable.cat8,R.drawable.cat9,R.drawable.cat10};

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        CustomList adapter = new
                CustomList(this.getActivity(), categorias, ImgCategorias);



        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // OLD ADAPTER (where only change the text, it works to the TextChangeListener)
     /*   adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.adapter_categorias, R.id.TVTitulo, categorias);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter2); */


        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text (LINE OF THE NULLPOINTER)
                Alimentacion.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

And the **CustomList.java**

```
    public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] categorias;
    private final Integer[] ImgCategorias;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] categorias, Integer[] ImgCategorias) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_categorias, categorias);
        this.context = context;
        this.categorias = categorias;
        this.ImgCategorias = ImgCategorias;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_categorias, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TVTitulo);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.IVCategoria);
        txtTitle.setText(categorias[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(ImgCategorias[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

In conclusion, I want if is posible have the images and the titles in diferents adapters and in the search function put only the adapter of the title. Or something that allows me search for the title with no error..
I have seen this question: [android attaching multiple adapters to one adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964259/android-attaching-multiple-adapters-to-one-adapter)
But I don't understand very well how to implement it to my app..

Thanks.

Comment: It's thowing exception becuase of:  Alimentacion.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); Comment this line.  You need to write the below inside aftertextChanged: String text = inputSearch..getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()); adapter.filter(text); Check if it works

Comment: No, I have the same error, if you see in my code I have an "adapter2" comented, if i put this adapter it works but this adapter only puts the title and the image is the same to all the single items.. Is any option to put adapter2 and change the image of the single item otherwise? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If it's possible to send the whole code in dropbox, then I could debug and fix. I did the same thing recently where it had one text & image and I could able to do search based on that.

Comment: I can't send all the project.. but in this zip is the full oncreateview code of the fragment, the layout of the fragment, the adapter of single item xml and the CustimList.java.. https://mega.co.nz/#!OMUxTQCK!Hri496abNu_pQX2n8vrHJObw6I2u63VSlBhe9a6Gkm0

Comment: Can I make as an activity instead of fragment here? It's upto you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code as below and it's working fine now. Please check and let me know:

```
public class Image {

    String categorias;
    Integer ImgCategorias;

    public String getCategorias() {
        return categorias;
    }
    public void setCategorias(String categorias) {
        this.categorias = categorias;
    }
    public Integer getImgCategorias() {
        return ImgCategorias;
    }
    public void setImgCategorias(Integer imgCategorias) {
        ImgCategorias = imgCategorias;
    }
}
```

Your Adapter class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Image> data;
    private  ArrayList<Image> listImage;

    public CustomList(Context context, ArrayList<Image> listImage) {
        this.context = context;
        data = listImage;
        this.listImage = new ArrayList<Image>();
        this.listImage.addAll(listImage);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter_categorias, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TVTitulo);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.IVCategoria);
        txtTitle.setText(data.get(position).getCategorias());
        imageView.setImageResource(data.get(position).getImgCategorias());
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        data.clear();
        if (charText.trim().length() == 0) {
            data.addAll(listImage);
        } else {
            for (Image wp : listImage) {
                if (wp.getCategorias().toLowerCase().contains(charText)) {
                    data.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Activity Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Alimentacion extends Activity {

    Context context;
    TextView txtTVtexto;
    EditText txtInputSearch;
    ListView list;
    CustomList adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_alimentacion);

        context = Alimentacion.this;

        txtTVtexto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVtexto);
        txtInputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        ArrayList<Image> listImage = prepareImageList();
        adapter = new CustomList(context, listImage);


        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            Image image = (Image) list.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Name: "+image.getCategorias(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });         

        txtInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                String text = "";
                try {
                    text = txtInputSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                adapter.filter(text);
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<Image> prepareImageList() {
        ArrayList<Image> listImage = new ArrayList<Image>();
        Image image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("1. Huevos y Lacteos");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        listImage.add(image);

        image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("2. Carnes y Derivados");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        listImage.add(image);

        image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("3. Pescados y Mariscos");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        listImage.add(image);

        image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("4. Aceites y grasos");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.ic_stub);
        listImage.add(image);

        image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("5. Verduras y hortalizas");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.share);
        listImage.add(image);

        image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("6. Frutas");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        listImage.add(image);

        image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("7. Bebidas");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        listImage.add(image);

        image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("8. Comida Rapida");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        listImage.add(image);

        image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("9. Pasta y Cereales");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        listImage.add(image);

        image = new Image();
        image.setCategorias("10. Bolleria y Snacks");
        image.setImgCategorias(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        listImage.add(image);

        return listImage;
    }
}
```

- Layout:

fragment_alimentacion.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="es.bawi.testdeporte.Alimentacion" >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TVtexto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Blank Fragment" />
    <!-- Editext for Search -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TVtexto"
        android:hint="Productos"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
    <!-- List View -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

adapter_categorias.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_height="70dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVCategoria"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TVTitulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IVCategoria"
        android:text="Categoria"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TVCalorias"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TVTitulo"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="Nº Productos"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



</RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Now i can write with no problems. but the filter doe snot work well, always i have the same result. Look: http://i.gyazo.com/9b4535c97b59dbe9b42034ed8b9d9948.gif

Comment: In getView() change  txtTitle.setText(categorias.get(position)); to  txtTitle.setText(data.get(position)); Also please mark the answer as resolved if It resolves your issue.

Comment: Okey, i marke as solved because now works, but i have a little problem that i don't know if you can help me. Now when i search something it changes the images look this: http://i.gyazo.com/ef00df8e3752cac5093ea4d28f8fc461.gif For example number 3. the icon is a fish but if I search 3. the icon change to the egg (number 1.)

Comment: :D I was about to suggest that one only. I know why it's happening. Hint: Prepare one class to set image & name. Then pass ArrayList<YourModel> to Adapter instead of separated array. It will resolve your issue. In case you couldn't do, let me know. I will update my code ehre.

Comment: bff.. sorry.. i did't worked with arrayList, etc in android.. and I don't know how to do that..

Comment: @Guixe94 I have updated the Activity & Adapter class. Now you can find text aligned with right image.

Comment: Cannot resolve method setCategorias and setImgCategorias of tha activity and getCategorias of the adapter. Where are this methods located?

Comment: Ohh I'm so sorry. I forgot to mention the "Image" class. See now I have added.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now works fine! The last thing.. if you see if have a code when users clicks a item that makes a toast that says " You clicked %nameOfCategory%" this is the code --> ' Toast.makeText(Alimentacion.this.getActivity(), "You clicked" +categorias[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();'  But the problem is the same, y you search for category 3 and you click the toast says that you clicked category 1. I suppose that is only change the 'categorias[+ position]' to the correct, but i don't know what i need to put. Thank! You save me!.

Comment: WC. Please check line list.setOnItemClickListener at Activity