# Android setting more than one adapter to one listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have 2 adapters, which each adapter contain different API i want to put into one listview. How can i set the second adapter without replacing the first one? Thanks before :)

```
pcAPI = (ArrayList<ListAPI>) parsepcAPI(pcTemp);
artistAPI = (ArrayList<ListAPI>) parseArtistAPI(artistTemp);

lvAPI = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAPI);

Song_APIAdapter adapter = new Song_APIAdapter(getApplicationContext(), pcAPI);
lvAPI.setAdapter(adapter);

Song_APIAdapter adapter2 = new Song_APIAdapter(getApplicationContext(), artistAPI);
lvAPI.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Comment: Can you describe what are the contents of the adapter may be there is solution?

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: add the items in pcAPI and artistAPI and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: If you want to show data from **two different api** then what you can do is **merge** both of the data in `one arraylist` and then using one `adpater` only you can show the both api data.

Comment: @Raghunandan they are music api data, like the name of the artist, the song, and playcount.

Comment: @AchillesJorgieRizaldyS i am not sure  yet of the content. But your list can have different view types. also check if commonsware merge adapter helps as posted by Renjith

Comment: how can it have different types? he is applying the same adapter to both the lists.

Comment: Thanks guys, it works. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try merging the 2 adapters into a single adapter like this :

[android attaching multiple adapters to one adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964259/android-attaching-multiple-adapters-to-one-adapter)

Or, you could merge the two `ArrayLists` into one and then set the `Adapter`. Effectively that is what you are doing.

Or you could set the `pcAPI` into the adapter first, then add `artistAPI` to `pcAPI` and then set the new adapter again. and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

why can't you simply do this?

```
pcAPI = (ArrayList<ListAPI>) parsepcAPI(pcTemp);
artistAPI = (ArrayList<ListAPI>) parseArtistAPI(artistTemp);

ArrayList<ListAPI> mergedList = new ArrayList<ListAPI>();
mergedList.addAll(pcAPI);
mergedList.add(artistAPI);

Song_APIAdapter adapter = new Song_APIAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mergedAPI);
lvAPI.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked :)
i'm new to android and often get confused haha

Comment: I am glad it did. You can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. That helps future users too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will merge the adapter

```
    Song_APIAdapter adapter = new Song_APIAdapter(getApplicationContext(), pcAPI);
    lvAPI.setAdapter(adapter);
    Song_APIAdapter adapter2 = new Song_APIAdapter(getApplicationContext(), artistAPI);
    adapter.addAdapter(adapter2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should not use 2 adapters for 1 listview. Adatper is the interface which converts data to view.

In your case, your listview is showing 2 kinds of data. so you should create a brand new adapter which read the data from pcAPI and artistAPI, then generates a new view and pass it to ListView.

If your just need show pcView and artistView alternately, there is a simple way:

1. create a new adapter, and pass adapter and adapter2 to it.
2. override getCount(), getCount = adapter.getCount()+adapter2.getCount();
3. override getView, for odd item return adapter.getView(...), for even item return adapter2.getCount();

I don't know want kind of view you want, so I just guess your requirements.