# how i can add two adapters to one listView (xamarin android)

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

i have two adapters and i want to merging the 2 adapters into a single adapter xamarin android

the first adapter :

```
 private ArrayAdapter _adapter;
```

the second adapter :

```
   class HomeScreenAdapterEmp : BaseAdapter<employer>
{
    List<employer> items;
    Activity context;
    int a;

    public HomeScreenAdapterEmp(Activity context, List<employer> items)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        //this.A = c;
    }
```

i want to merging the 2 adapters into a single adapter

```
   _adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
    Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, TableEmp);//2
        listView.Adapter = _adapter;//2


        listView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapterEmp(this, TableEmp);// 1
        listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick;//1

        sv.QueryTextChange += Sv_QueryTextChange;

        listView.ItemClick += ListView_ItemClick1;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964259/android-attaching-multiple-adapters-to-one-adapter - maybe this could help

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Any update?

Comment: @Grace thanks for your answer but unfortunately i dont get the right result here is what im trying to do : i want to add a filter to my listview i found a good solution here  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB5UW7VFHwU)  the prolem is thats i already have an adapter when i use your methode i got this result [link](http://hpics.li/61a574e)

Comment: @MédSiràj, OK...I understand now, you only want a listview filter, it's not about merging two adapters into one at all.......You can check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android

Answer (score 0):

As Yupi suggested, you can create your `MergeAdapter`, but in your code I find that your `ArrayAdapter` and `HomeScreenAdapterEmp` have the same data resource `TableEmp`? Based on your code `List<employer> items;`, this `TableEmp` should be the type `List<employer>`. Is this a typo?

Anyway, you can create your `MergeAdapter` for example like this:

```
public class MergeAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    protected List<IListAdapter> pieces = new List<IListAdapter>();
    protected string noItemsText;

    public MergeAdapter()
    {
    }

    public void AddAdapter(IListAdapter adapter)
    {
        pieces.Add(adapter);
        adapter.RegisterDataSetObserver(new CascadeDataSetObserver());
    }

    private class CascadeDataSetObserver : DataSetObserver
    {
        public override void OnChanged()
        {
            base.OnChanged();
        }

        public override void OnInvalidated()
        {
            base.OnInvalidated();
        }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            int total = 0;
            foreach (var piece in pieces)
            {
                total += piece.Count;
            }
            if (total == 0 && noItemsText != null)
            {
                total = 1;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        foreach (var piece in pieces)
        {
            int size = piece.Count;
            if (position < size)
                return (piece.GetItem(position));
            position -= size;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override int ViewTypeCount
    {
        get
        {
            int total = 0;
            foreach (var piece in pieces)
            {
                total += piece.ViewTypeCount;
            }
            return (Java.Lang.Math.Max(total, 1));
        }
    }

    public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        int typeOffset = 0;
        int result = -1;

        foreach (var piece in pieces)
        {
            int size = piece.Count;
            if (position < size)
            {
                result = typeOffset + piece.GetItemViewType(position);
                break;
            }
            position -= size;
            typeOffset += piece.ViewTypeCount;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        foreach (var piece in pieces)
        {
            int size = piece.Count;
            if (position < size)
            {
                return (piece.GetItemId(position));
            }
            position -= size;
        }
        return (-1);
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        foreach (var piece in pieces)
        {
            int size = piece.Count;
            if (position < size)
                return piece.GetView(position, convertView, parent);
            position -= size;
        }
        if (noItemsText != null)
        {
            TextView text = new TextView(parent.Context);
            text.Text = noItemsText;
            return text;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void SetNoItemText(string text)
    {
        noItemsText = text;
    }

    public IListAdapter GetAdapter(int position)
    {
        foreach (var piece in pieces)
        {
            int size = piece.Count;
            if (position < size)
                return piece;
            position -= size;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ListView lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lv);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    TableEmp.Add(new employer() { ID = i, Name = "Name " + i });
    _stringEmp.Add("Item " + i);
}
var _adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, _stringEmp);

var homeadapter = new HomeScreenAdapterEmp(this, TableEmp);

var mergeadapter = new MergeAdapter();
mergeadapter.AddAdapter(_adapter);
mergeadapter.AddAdapter(homeadapter);
mergeadapter.SetNoItemText("No Item");
lv.Adapter = mergeadapter;
```