# How to create multiple adapters for a single ListView?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

What I want to do is simple application that shows a menu which let the user switch between contents by selecting different topics in that menu [image: (like the pic)]

The content exists in a ListView, so it needs an adapter, the contents are different and contains images that loading from URL, I have made different adapters to match the different contents and let ListView switch between them by setting the target adapter for what the user has pressed in the Menu, and that happens in each pressing time, but the problem is that in each time I set the target adapter for the ListView those images in the contents reload from the URL because the method GetView() has being recalled in each time in the adapter, so what I can do to prevent them from reloading?
I know I can create multiple list views but I think that isn't a good way..

Comment: What language is that for. Tags on Stackoverflow are not like tweets you don't put all of them, just relevant ones.

Comment: @Aboud, According to your description, you want to click different menu item do display different content for ListView, I suggest you can go to different activity to display different content ListView,https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/xamarin-opening-another-activity-in-android-application/

Comment: @Franck, c#, I tagged java too, because it nears to c# and I can understand it

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I know that, but I don't want that navigation animation to show when navigate between activities, so I decided to use single activity, and it will consume memory for nothing

Comment: @Aboud,I find one sample thread about using MergeAdapter to add multiple adapters, you can take  look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602812/how-i-can-add-two-adapters-to-one-listview-xamarin-android

Answer (score 0):

Cache the images on the filesystem when you first download them. When you load an image, check the cache, and download the images only if they're not yet cached.  If they are, load them from the filesystem instead.

Comment: How I can do that? is there an example project or documentation for that?

Answer (score -1):

Try using glide or Picasso to load images in different list views. Glide internally caches images using their url as a key to retrieve cache. That way when your images are loaded once in any of your list view, they can be cached for future use in other list views. However, you will still need to create new instances of the image view as you will be using a completely different listview. You CAN create your own factory of image view with content (image) populated inside them and get such views based on unique keys (that you will define yourself which can be pain) but that would be an overkill for very little outcome.

Comment: THis has nothing to do with his questions.  Moving to a recycler view won't solve his problems.  ListViews also support multiple view types.  He's asking about not reloading images from the network, totally different question.

Comment: I will try those libraries, but why I need to create multiple list views?

Comment: @AboudShehap you don't need to create but as you said you have to show different lists when you select those menu options in nav drawer.