# How to View Adapter1, Adapter2, Adapter3 in a Single ListView Note I use Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to View Adapter1, Adapter2, Adapter3 in a Single ListView Note I use Xamarin

```
listViewDrInfo.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, tableItems);        

listViewDrInfo.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter3(this, tableItemsWorkTime);

listViewDrInfo.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter2(this, tableItemsInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can't do this.

Instead, make a new adapter whose array has all the elements from all three adapters, IOW combine tableItems, tableItemsWorkTime, and tableItemsInfo into one array (or whatever collection type you are using).

*Not directly anyway. see this So thread for possible ideas:
[android attaching multiple adapters to one adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964259/android-attaching-multiple-adapters-to-one-adapter) , but those are basically combining the adapters to one adapter using a couple of different methods.